# Building a digital signage platform in HTML5

Tags: jquery, html, actionscript-3

I need some feedback! So if any help, Thank you!

I'm a developer for a digital signage company. We built a platform in Flash (ActionScript 3) and it has been running really smooth for a few years now. We've been talking about trying to move to HTML5, JQUERY and PHP for a while now. Flash is super nice because it gives me an easy way to arrange components onto the screen. I know flash is probably on its way out and I'm sure that will be a while from now but we would like to move into the future.

**Alright, here is the issue i'm facing:**
With HTML5, i'm trying to fit for different screen resolutions. Of course I'm using a responsive CSS framework (materializecss) but in flash i've used:

```
stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_BORDER;
stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.EXACT_FIT;
```

This would scale our platform to fit any screen size - It kept everything together. It would just zoom things up like it was one photo for example.

In HTML5 I feel like I can't get this to do the same thing. Do you know what I mean? Maybe I won't be able to get the same layout like I have in flash with HTML5? Would we have to re-design our layout?

I guess my question for this whole post is if you look at the screen shot of our current platform built in flash. Look at the way things are layout. How could that layout be built in HTML5 and have it to keep/scale the same layout on all different screen resolutions from 1280x720 and Up. 16.9 layouts

Comment: Do you have a sample 'sign'? if this is just vector graphics, SVG (Scalable Vector Graphics http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/) a part of HTML5 should be able to scale as you need.

Comment: Nothing is SVG. Mostly jpgs. I've edited and posted an example of what our screen layout looks like! Thanks!

Comment: createJS is HTML5 display library that makes for an easy transition for Flash users.

Comment: @Batman - Thank you. I will bookmark this!  - I guess my question for this whole post is if you look at the screen shot of our current platform built in flash. Look at the way things are layout. How could that layout be built in HTML5 and have it to keep/scale the same layout on all different screen resolutions from 1280x720 and Up. 16.9 layouts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSS gives you a lot of different metrics for sizing things.  The most obvious way to scale relative to an existing size (such as the size of the body itself) is through percentages.  Your left column is going to be about `33%` width, and your right column should be left to fill the remaining space on its own.

Now for the text, I prefer to set my font sizes with `em`.  This is a relative sizing metric.  That is, `1.2em` is 120% the size of whatever the text size is in the parent.  The reason this is useful is that `1em` is set to a readable size on all devices.  As a web developer, I don't know all the information about how my sites will be viewed and on what devices.  This lets me set a good scaling point.  If you know something about general aspect ratios and sizes, you might consider setting a more explicit size.  Note that I would still use `em` everywhere but the `body` element in this case.

Your lower-third ticker should be placed relative to the footer of the page.  Position absolute and set `bottom: 1em` or something like that.  The user's logo should be in the same container so it all gets positioned together.

Finally, the slideshow component should take up 100% of its container, minus padding.

Basically, you want to build a robust layout that is configured in such a way that it will work on almost any aspect ratio and size.  Think about what items are *really* relative to and write your CSS accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

I've been doing a lot of signage design using Twitter Bootstrap and adjusting the container max-widths based on typical display sizes (720p, 1080p, UHD 4K). For responsive measurements on almost everything, instead of pixels or em, you could use `vw` or `vh` —ratios based on either the viewport-width or viewport-height. These will allow you to scale your elements dynamically. Both units are supported for pretty much anything in your layout based on screen-size: fonts, divs, images, etc.

Example:

```
.yourElement {
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow: 0.1vh 0.1vh 0.3vh black;
  padding-top: 2.5vh;
  padding-bottom: 4vh;
}
.yourElement h1, h2 {
  font-size: 3vh;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Appreciate that!